# SVG Change Fill Color with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a handful of SVG images that are all similar to this image (white image with transparent background) **(See Rain SVG)**

Is there any CSS that I can use to change the main-fill to any color without filling the whole image? 
    **HTML:**

```
<button class={style.sbutton} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
    <Icon class={style.rainIcon} src={Rain} />
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.rainIcon 
fill: #ffa07f;
}
```

[image: Cloud SVG]

Comment: can you show the html output?

Comment: It would be nice to attach svg to your question.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you:
in order to be able to change the fill color the svg has to be in the page. if you are placing it as a background image then this is not possible.

```
<style>
    a.icon{fill: blue;}
</style>

    <a href="#" class="icon">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <use xlink:href="#circle" />
        </svg>
    </a>

    <div style="display:none">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: How would I do this with an image, not a circle?

Answer (score 0):

I see below as an alternative to the above with image as background.
but there is another one Filters but you should really check out with the browser support. reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

```
    <style>
        /*a.icon{fill: blue;}*/
        a.imageIcon{
            display:inline-block;
            width:24px;
            height:24px;
            background-image:url('assets/imageIcon-blue.svg');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            }
        a.imageIcon:hover{
            background-image:url('assets/imageIcon-green.svg');
            }

    </style>

<!--    <a href="#" class="icon"> <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"> <use xlink:href="#circle" /></svg></a>    -->

    <a href="#" class="imageIcon"> </a>

   <!-- <div style="display:none">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
            </symbol>
        </svg>
    </div>-->
```